# Bootstrap 3 - full width sub-menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my sub-menu have the same width as the entire parent menu, however of course the sub-menu is taking on the width of it's parent li. I also need the sub-menu li items to be floated left next to each other - i tried doing padding: 0 -421%; on dropdown-menu which made it the same width as the actual parents menu, but of course i cannot float the li's inside the dropdown menu due to the extra padding.

The **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ePy/)**

```
<a href="/">
```

(added as i keep getting "jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" error).

Comment: A fiddle would be here of great interest to you.

Comment: Please put up the code or try to recreate the situation in jsfiddle.

Comment: when i understand your question well, you can use the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449960/full-width-bootstrap-dropdown-nav too, demo: http://www.bootply.com/E8DurpOyBi

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .dropdown-menu {
     width:597px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu li {
     float: left;
  }
```

Not the best of approach,but this should give you what you were looking for.

Comment: Almost, but the li's are still stacked, having added a float left all of the li's are now on top of each other (not stacked, but literally overlaying each other).

Comment: They're still stacking on top of each other, rather than floating next to each other unfortunately.

Comment: @NikkiMather You want them arranged horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

As your submenu seems to only be used on large devices, I would suggest to fix its width :

```
@media (min-width:991px) {
    #slidemenu .dropdown-menu {
        width: 910px; 
        padding: 5px;
    }
}
```

Why `910px` :

> {container size} - {container horizontal padding} - {navbar-collapse horizontal padding}
>   = 970 - (15 + 15) - (15 + 15)
>   = 910